# Experiments with azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Good day , I'm new in azure blob and don't know what kinds of experiments can be done with it, I have searched  about it but still isn't clear to me. I'll be really gratefull if you can tell me  about easy experiments that can be done in azure blob.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "experiments with blob storage". Blob storage allows you to store huge amount of binary/unstructured data cheaply. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob storage stores unstructured data such as text, binary data, documents or media files.

Hope you meant the samples or the operations that can be done using azure blob when you say experiments.

1. You can do operations like uploading the files, downloading , listing etc. programmatically or through the UI.
2. You can above operations using languages such  as .Net, Java,Python,JS..etc which you can find links in this documentation [Azure Storage samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-dotnet?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)
3. But to access Azure Storage, you'll need an Azure subscription or free trial account. All access to Azure Storage takes place through a storage account. For this quickstart, create a storage account using the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
   Refer to [Create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal)

[image]

4. You can do above operations in portal directly .This sample [blog](https://azurelessons.com/create-azure-blob-storage/) can give you quick insights to perform them through portal.
5. A number of solutions exist for migrating existing data to Blob storage like AzCopy ,Azure datafactory etc
   [Introduction to Blob (object) storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)